# How to ignore some lines in a maven pre-commit code formatter

Tags: java, git, maven, code-formatting

I have a project that is using `git-code-format-maven-plugin` from `com.cosium.code` to format code as a pre-commit hook.

I want to ignore auto formatting in some cases (like a long list of method parameters). E.g.

```
    Assert.assertEquals(
        1000L,
        client.add(
            "stackoverflow",
            1000L,
            0.01,
            100000L /*SomeParameter*/,
            true,
            10000L,
            SomeEnum.NONE,
            someLabels));
```

Is there any way to keep the above code within fewest possible lines? E.g.

```
    Assert.assertEquals(1000L, client.add("stackoverflow", 1000L, 0.01,
            100000L /*SomeParameter*/, true, 10000L, SomeEnum.NONE, someLabels));
```

Or, is there any other maven plugin with which it is possible to do that?

PS: My question is not for Assert statements only. It is for a long list of method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem supported natively.

As shown in [`Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin` issue 55](https://github.com/Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin/issues/55), you would need to add your own formatter by extending [`google/google-java-format`](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) in order to:

- detect an Assert statement
- format it as you want to.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest any other maven code-formatter plugin?